# toggle button text on a timer with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a working **toggle button** text code but I would like the button to toggle **back** to the `original state` after **4 seconds**.

I have tried looking for a solution and can't wrap my head around whether I need to use a `setInterval` function or `setTimeout` function and how to implement them exactly.

Hopefully, a javascript wizard can help me out here.

```js
function myFunctionbutton() {
  var x = document.getElementById("singleadd");
  if (x.innerHTML === "add to bag") {
    x.innerHTML = "Loading...";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "add to bag";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="singleadd" onclick="myFunctionbutton()">add to bag</button>
```

Comment: You should lookup the functionality and usage of both `setInterval` and `setTimeout`. Go visit https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: In your case you should use setTimeout(), because the function executes only once after the timeout, while setInterval() executes in intervals again and again every **X** seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function to get back to `"add to bag"` state after **4 seconds**.

Also, if you want you can [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/disabled) the button for that **4 seconds**, so that the user cannot click again untill 4 seconds are over.

```js
function myFunctionbutton() {
  var x = document.getElementById("singleadd");
  x.disabled = true;
  x.innerText = "Loading...";
  setTimeout(() => {
     x.innerText = "add to bag";
     x.disabled = false;
  }, 4000);
  
}
```

```html
<button id="singleadd" onclick="myFunctionbutton()">add to bag</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

```js
function myFunctionbutton() {
  var x = document.getElementById("singleadd");
  if (x.innerHTML === "add to bag") {
    x.innerHTML = "Loading...";
    setTimeout(function () {
      x.innerHTML = "add to bag"
    }, 4000);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="singleadd" onclick="myFunctionbutton()">add to bag</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval` and provide interval in miliseconds.

```js
function myFunctionbutton() {
  var x = document.getElementById("singleadd");
  if (x.innerHTML === "add to bag") {
    x.innerHTML = "Loading...";
  } 
  setInterval(function(){ x.innerHTML = "add to bag"; }, 4000);
}
```

```html
<button id="singleadd" onclick="myFunctionbutton()">add to bag</button>
```